# Omit duplicate values in one column and show the rest

Tags: select

I am starting with SQL, so my question will be easy for you.

I have **one table** with many columns. Most important are [Test number] and [Start time]. [Test number] contains many duplicated rows and [Start time] contains always unique records. And now I want to show in results all table columns, where only the [Test number] with maximum [Start time] will be used.

I was able to create one result regarding the maximum [Start time]

```
SELECT MAX([Start time])
FROM [Testing_ADB_Overview].[dbo].[HTT_DB]
GROUP BY [Test number]
ORDER BY MAX([Start time])
```

but I do not know how can I apply it to see in results all the other columns. Can you please help me?

MF

Comment: Help us help - share some sample data and the result you'd like to get to it

Comment: Start time is nvarchar with this format: 190923_132819 (YearMonthDay_HourMinuteSencond)

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the `[Test number]` for the last `[Stat time]`. You can do it in two ways:

1. Store in a variable (`@MaxStatTime`) the result of the max from your select. Make a query of the `[Test number]` with the following where condition `[Start time] = @MaxStartTime` and store it in another variable (`@LastTestNumber`). And just retrieve the rows from your table corresponding to `@LastTestNumber`.
2. Using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, you can order descending your rows in the table by the `[Stat time]` column. Then by filtering the table for `row_number() = 1`, you can obtain the `[Test number]`, and again retrieve the rows from your table.

I'm not that fond about the 1st solution, so I will skip it's implementation, but here is an implementation of the 2nd solution using common table expression to make it more readable:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#HTT_DB') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #HTT_DB
    CREATE TABLE #HTT_DB 
        ( [Test number] NVARCHAR(100)
        , [Start time] NVARCHAR(100)
        )

INSERT INTO #HTT_DB( [Test number], [Start time] )
VALUES
    ('AA' , '210525_090000')
    ,('BB', '210525_080000') 
    ,('CC', '210525_070000') 
    ,('BB', '210525_060000') 
    ,('AA', '210525_050000') 

;WITH OrderedTestNumber AS (SELECT [Test number], [Start time], ROW_NUMBER()  OVER ( PARTITION BY [Test number] ORDER BY [Start time] DESC) RowNo FROM #HTT_DB)
SELECT htt.* 
FROM #HTT_DB  htt INNER JOIN OrderedTestNumber otm ON otm.[Test number] = htt.[Test number] AND otm.[Start time] = htt.[Start time]
WHERE otm.RowNo = 1
```

Output:

| Test number | Start time |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 210525_090000 |
| BB | 210525_080000 |
| CC | 210525_070000 |

I would strongly advice adding a primary key column to ta table [HTT_DB], let's say PK_Column for the sake of simplicity. The query would bi simplifed as:

```
;WITH OrderedTestNumber AS (SELECT PK_Column, ROW_NUMBER()  OVER ( PARTITION BY [Test number] ORDER BY [Start time] DESC) RowNo FROM #HTT_DB)
SELECT htt.* 
FROM #HTT_DB  htt INNER JOIN OrderedTestNumber otm ON otm.PK_Column = htt.PK_Column
WHERE otm.RowNo = 1
```

Comment: Hello lakta,

thank you for your effort and answer. I tried your solution (just copy and paste) but I received the errors:

Msg 10753, Level 15, State 3, Line 2
The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TOP'.

As a beginner I do not know how to handle it. Did I make some mistake? Or should I declare anything? I really like the second solution - seems to me really nice.  Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Hello lakta, thanks, now it is working! But not the way I wanted... 
My table:
[Test number], [Start date]
AA , 210525_090000
BB , 210525_080000
CC , 210525_070000
BB, 210525_060000
AA 210525_050000

It can happen (and it does) that even if the tests are sorted by time, other tests will take place between them. The [Test number] result is there more than once. I think it could be prevented by using that GROUP BY [Test number] in your code. This will ensure that only the [Test number] that has the most recent (highest) time results in the result. Am I right? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, it seems I have misinterpreted your question. This is the reason for asking for sample data and preferred outcome. Does you table have a primary key? I was under the impression that the [Test number] would be primary key, and can be used identify the select the correct row. Your desired outcome is AA, 210525_090000 BB, 210525_080000 CC, 210525_070000 ?

Comment: I have edited the my answer with sample data. The [Test number] can not be a primary key, it must be unique

Comment: Aha, I am sorry. No - Test number is not a primary key. And yes, I need exactly the result you wrote.